# Hadoop process with no name in jps

Tags: hadoop

I'm new in hadoop and I was wondering how can I know what process is this one with no name (id 13333)

```
hadoop@hadoop-mymachine:~$ jps
13050 NodeManager
12818 ResourceManager
12403 DataNode
12654 SecondaryNameNode
13347 Jps
12200 NameNode
13333
```

everything else in hadoop seems fine, hadoop works fine, I just want to know how to identify that process

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ps command to get the details.

```
ps aux | grep 13333
```

Not sure, you will get the details if you use `jps -l`

Answer (score -1):

It might be one of the Orphan process.

You can use ps command to get more information about the process.

**ps -ef | grep 13333**